# How does Laravel validation return Exception as Json without try catch?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'm bulding an exception log into my Laravel app to send mails or Telegram messages when an error identified as important is dispatched. 
Actually, I'm using a 'try catch' block on each of my controller functions to catch an exception dispathced by any part of my app.
My question is, how does Laravel validation works to return exceptions as JSON response without using `return` sentences or `try catch` blocks on each call?

What I must do now into controller:

```php
someAction();

try {
    Model::someFunction($params);
catch (MyCustomException $e)
    return json()->response($e->getMessage(), 500); // Return json error if fails
}

return anotherAction();
```

What I want to do into controller:

```php
someAction();

Model::someFunction($params); // Return json error if fails and stop execution

return anotherAction();
```

What Laravel validation makes:

```php
someAction();

$request->validate($validationRules); // Return json error if validation fails and stop execution

return anotherAction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a validator

```
<?php

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller {

    public function myFunction(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'foo' => 'required',
            'bar' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->passes()) {

        }

        if ($validator->fails()) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not asking how to validate. I'm asking how laravel validation works when validation fails, how does it return json response and stops execution, because I want to implement the same at my code